# Endereco de pasta e imagem com bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, arquivo, carousel

Como eu modifico esta DIV para aceitar uma pasta e nome de imagem?

```
**<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three');"></div>**
```

Mudo para 'pasta/nomeArquivo.jpg' e nao carrega a imagem.

Observem parte do codigo que estou tentando fazer ler as imagens. Elas estao em uma pasta chamada no mesmo nivel do arquivo index.htm chamada fCapa, e todas as imagens sao renomeadas automaticamente para ter uma sequencia, por isso (1).jpg, (2).jpg, e assim por diante, mas.... nao carregam em tela.`

```
      <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('fCapa/(1).jpg');">
        </div>  
            <div class="carousel-caption"><h2>Caption 1</h2>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('fCapa/(2).jpg');">
        </div>
                    <div class="carousel-caption"><h2>Caption 2</h2>
                    </div>
            </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('fCapa/(3).jpg');">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-caption"><h2>Caption 3</h2>
            </div>
            </div>
</div>

<!-- Controls -->
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, danestudo! Sugiro que você inclua sempre trechos do seu código (ou ele inteiro, se não for tão longo), porque isso costuma facilitar aos outros usuários entenderem o seu problema e acharem uma solução. Leia [nesse link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) sobre o que eu estou falando!

Comment: Podem ser várias coisas. Para a gente poder ajudar, favor [edit] a pergunta e indicar sua estrutura de pastas, onde está o arquivo que contém essa div, e onde está a imagem.

Comment: Senhores, nao tem como explicar mais claramente. Olhem: O codigo de origem carrega em uma DIV uma imagem de um servdor http, como faco para mudar para abertura de uma imagem em uma pasta local? Asim consigo subir para carregar em uma pasta adequada na publicacao do site. Nao tem jeito mais simples de explicar.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo se for pra fazer um **Carousel**, você não pode chamar a imagem na `div` atraves do **CSS**, tente fazer assim:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="fCapa/(1).jpg" alt="Imagem 1">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <!--Aqui vai a descrição da imagem-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="fCapa/(2).jpg" alt="Imagem 2">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <!--Aqui vai a descrição da imagem-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Creio que você tenha a parte de controle do **Carousel**, caso não tenha, segue o link de referência: [Bootstrap Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)